# How to monitor RAM ECC errors on Ivy Bridge Xeon E3 processor in Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, hardware, intel

How can I monitor if there are any errors in RAM that get corrected by ECC? The processor is an Intel Xeon (Ivy Bridge) processor, the operating system is Scientific Linux 6.3. On a previous system I had an AMD CPU, and on that system I could use edac-util to get this info, and it would also issue alerts to the kernel log.

Comment: Here is what happens when I run edac commands on the Intel system. Sorry for the poor formatting.

# edac-util / "edac-util: Fatal: Unable to get EDAC data: Unable to find EDAC data in sysfs"  | # edac-ctl --status / "edac-ctl: drivers not loaded." | # edac-ctl --mainboard / 
"edac-ctl: mainboard: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. P8C WS"

Comment: What's your chip set? Also check the output of `(z)grep CONFIG_EDAC_ /proc/config(.gz)`

Comment: It's C216 (an LGA 1155 workstation board). I don't have /proc/config*, but maybe /boot/config-2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64 does the same, in that case I get:
`# CONFIG_EDAC_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_EDAC_DECODE_MCE=m
# CONFIG_EDAC_MCE_INJ is not set
CONFIG_EDAC_MM_EDAC=m
CONFIG_EDAC_MCE=y
CONFIG_EDAC_AMD64=m
# CONFIG_EDAC_AMD64_ERROR_INJECTION is not set
CONFIG_EDAC_E752X=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I82975X=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I3000=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I3200=m
CONFIG_EDAC_X38=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I5400=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I7CORE=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I5000=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I5100=m
CONFIG_EDAC_I7300=m
CONFIG_EDAC_SBRIDGE=m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for as I can find only E5 Xeons are supported with the sb_edac module

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-edac/msg00846.html

Answer (score 3):

Since version 3.17 of the Linux kernel, ECC errors on E3 Xeons can be monitored using the `ie31200_edac` driver, introduced by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7ee40b897d18ab03111eda9a6a0550e98166eada). This uses the standard EDAC interface so errors can be listed using `edac-util`.

In a little more detail:

```
sudo modprobe ie31200-edac
```

loads the driver, which will result in lines like

```
[   14.635299] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[   14.637898] EDAC MC0: Giving out device to module ie31200_edac controller IE31200: DEV 0000:00:00.0 (POLLED)
```

appearing in the kernel log (that’s on a C216 Haswell system); then

```
edac-util
```

will report any errors.

Xeon D, E5 and E7 memory controllers are supported using the `sb_edac` or `skx_edac` modules.